# Flutter with Bluetooth

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

I am building an app in flutter which uses bluetooth for checking whether any 2 users of the app is in contact of less than 1 metre then their phone must vibrate. Does anyone know how to implement this or any other new way to do this ? Thanks in advance , Please help as i am new to flutter .

Answer (score 1):

You can start by using this plugin [FlutterBlue](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue)  and calculate the user's distance using the RSSI value.

It's always a good idea to try something first and post it here though :)

Comment: Hi Brother, what is the formula to calc RSSI value?

Comment: Hi, I will search for it and post it once I finds it

Comment: I mean with Flutter Blue API what we can do to calc, Is it just RSSI or any variable that can be used? 
Thanks!